# No resource identifier found for attribute 'preset_size' for any res/

Tags: android, xml, facebook, android-layout, android-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.facebook.widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/selection_profile_pic"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        facebook:preset_size="small" />
```

I keep receiving the error No resource identifier found for attribute 'preset_size' in package com.facebook.widget although I looked at the class and the preset_size is under that package. Thanks in advance. I have tried setting the xmlns:facebook part to xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" and res/com.facebook.samples.profilepicture as well to no avail.

Comment: Do you have the FacebookSDK project added as well? If you have created your project from the samples folder, the FacebookSDK isn't included. The FacebookSDK is located in the root of the zip: /facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1/facebook/ and not in the /samples/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project -> properties -> android -> add correct libraries

("FacebookSDK", not "facebook")

Comment: thank you so much !! I didn't know the solution could be that simple

Comment: @user2486523: where do you find "Project" tab/button that you mentioned in Android Studio?